# How to add List items in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
if (option.generatePagination) {
    elem.append('<ul class=' + option.paginationClass + '></ul>');
    control.children().each(function () {
        $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#' + number + '">' + (number + 1) + '</a></li>');
        number++;
    });
} else {
    $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', '#' + number);
        number++;
    });
}
$('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq(' + start + ')', elem).addClass('current');
$('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem).click(function () {
    if (option.play) {
        pause();
    }
```

I'd like to add `<li class="prev"><a href="">Previous</a></li>` as the first list item, and `<li class="next"><a href="">Next</a></li>` as the last list item.

So:

```
<ul>
<li class="prev"><a href="">Previous</a></li>
<li><a href="#' + number + '">' + (number + 1) + '</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

How could i do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul').prepend('<li class="prev"><a href="">Previous</a></li>').append('<li class="next"><a href="">Next</a></li>');
```